# Get process id with Windows Cmd

Tags: windows

I used that cmd

`tasklist /v /fi "imagename EQ Wireshark.exe" /FO LIST | FIND "PID:"` but it return:

`PID:          28972`

I want to get only the number please

Answer (score 2):

Stop using the antiquated command line and use PowerShell

```powershell
(Get-Process Wireshark).id
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to store the output of your command and then parse it:

```
tasklist /v /fi "imagename EQ Wireshark.exe" /FO LIST | FIND "PID:" > %temp%\temp.txt
set /p variable= <%temp%\temp.txt
echo %variable:~17%
```

... but I'd strongly recommend to follow Gerald's answer and use PowerShell.

Comment: I agree that powershell is a better option but you don't need the temp file.  It is sloppy.  `for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %n in ('tasklist /v /fi "imagename EQ notepad.exe" /FO LIST ^| FIND "PID:"') do set /a PID_NUMBER=%n`